# Simplovation.Web.Maps.VE is not working with Ajax control toolkit

Tags: ajax, maps, controls, toolkit

I am using Simplovation.Web.Maps.VE version 4.0 and Ajax control toolkit version 4.1.7.1213.but Simplovation.Web.Maps.VE is not working with this version of ajax. It works only with ajax control toolkit older version. Is there any rules for Simplovation.Web.Maps.VE?
I have to work Simplovation.Web.Maps.VE with ajax control toolkit version 4.1.7.1213.how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, Replace your Ajax Control Toolkit with this version to work, [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=ajaxcontroltoolkit&DownloadId=670535&FileTime=130117808751070000&Build=20928). Maps.VE will work only on lower version.

Comment: but i have two asynchronous file upload,if i use Ajax control toolkit version 4.1.7.1213 both should works well,in older version only one asynchronous file upload works.that's why i moved to Ajax control toolkit version 4.1.7.1213.that time Simplovation.Web.Maps.VE  wont works